# c++ - copy constructor for singly linked circular list

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I want to make my own copy constructor for singly linked circular list.
Here is my code for the constructor.

```
CCircularList::CCircularList(CCircularList& srcList) // Copy Constructor
{
    Node* sPtr = srcList.top; // source pointer, top points to first entry in the list
    Node* dPtr = top = new Node(*sPtr); // dPtr is destination pointer, 
    sPtr = sPtr->next;

    while (sPtr != srcList.top)
    {
        dPtr->next = new Node(*sPtr);
        sPtr = sPtr->next;
        dPtr = dPtr->next;
    }
    setPosition(srcList.getPosition());
    dPtr->next = top;

}
```

This is not working correctly. After initializing a list using copy constructor, I get this error when I try to display it.

Unhandled exception at 0x011F3C99 in Circular List.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Here is copy constructor of Node class.

```
Node::Node(Node& newNode) // Copy constructor
{
    nData = newNode.nData; // Visual studio points to this line when giving error
    next = newNode.next;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should do null pointer check

Comment: I think this question is hard to get answer; We don't know the whole code of CCircularList, what the function setPosition/getPosition does and class Node's copy constructor is implemented correctly (have nothing to do when you want to make shallow copy list)...

Comment: I agree with @benlong. Your "access violation" could be happening in the second line of this function when you deref sPtr. I wouldn't be surprised if this copy ctor is being triggered at an unexpected time. (Also: where are your initializers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is incomplete. You must ensure first that CCircularList& srcList is correctly constructed. Also, the node constructor seems some wrong idea since you copy the reference node data and next address. I think the more correct may be some like

```
Node::Node(const Node& oldNode)
: nData(oldNode.nData)
, next(nullptr)
{;}
```

Indeeed, the error suggest that some sPtr you pass is null. You can check with assert doing

```
CCircularList::CCircularList(CCircularList& srcList) // Copy Constructor
{
    Node* sPtr = srcList.top; // source pointer, top points to first entry in the list
    assert(sPtr);
    Node* dPtr = top = new Node(*sPtr); // dPtr is destination pointer, 
    sPtr = sPtr->next;

    while (sPtr != srcList.top)
    {
        assert(sPtr);
        dPtr->next = new Node(*sPtr);
        sPtr = sPtr->next;
        dPtr = dPtr->next;
    }
    setPosition(srcList.getPosition());
    dPtr->next = top;
}
```